# How to remove html tags from html documents using mongodb

Tags: html, mongodb, tags

I am using mongodb version 3.2.4. I have a collection with only one filed, Html (except id, ofc). There are altogether 8.821.851 documents. Every document represent html file with around 5 pages of plain text, but around 20 pages with html tags.

When I try simple queries that search for documents that contain some text (for example where ID number is "5555888" or name is "John"), it doesn't return any result or I have to wait for a long time.

I would like remove html tags from all documents to decrease the size of all files. Then it would be faster to query specific documents.

Is there a solution in Mongodb for this task?

Example of one html document (small part):

```
"<a name=\"JR_PAGE_ANCHOR_0_1\"></a>\n<table style=\"width: 595px; border-collapse: collapse; empty-cells: show\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" bgcolor=\"white\">\n<tr>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 40px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 22px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 108px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 88px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 117px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 80px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 79px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 1px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 1px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"11\" style=\"width: 595px; height: 20px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"2\" style=\"width: 60px; height: 46px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"2\"><img src=\"/servlets/PublicReportServlet?_image_=img_0_0_9\" style=\"height: 46px\" alt=\"\"/></td>\n  <td colspan=\"6\" style=\"text-align: right;\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 18.0px; font-weight: bold;\">NESLUŽBENA KOPIJA</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 46px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">REPUBLIKA HRVATSKA</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td colspan=\"11\" style=\"width: 595px; height: 4px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">Općinski sud u Novom Zagrebu</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">ZEMLJIŠNOKNJIŽNI ODJEL NOVI ZAGREB</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"4\" style=\"border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #000000; \"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">Stanje na dan: 19.06.2016 23:05</span></td>\n  <td colspan=\"5\" style=\"border-bottom-style: solid; border-bottom-width: 1px; border-bottom-color: #000000; text-align: right;\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px;\">Verificirani poduložak</span></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"9\"></td>\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n</tr>\n<tr valign=\"top\">\n  <td style=\"width: 20px; height: 12px;\"></td>\n  <td colspan=\"5\"><span style=\"font-family: Times New Roman; color: #000000; font-size: 10.0px; font-weight: bold;\">Knjiga PU: ZAPRUDSKI OTOK
```

Comment: Tasks like these are best done on the client. MongoDB is supposed to be a big, dumb data store - it does almost no processing, just storing and retrieving data. You should respect this goal and try to avoid forcing MongoDB to do any computation that could be done on the client.

Comment: You need to use an HTML Parser to parse your document and remove those tags then use the result to update your documents? Which language driver are you using?

Comment: Ok. Can I use Python or R to do this and how?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you have a huge collection in MongoDB and you want to edit each document on that collection. The document edit is more-or-less string editing & processing.

This is not a task for MongoDB. You should use some MongoDB client or driver and write a very simple code maybe in c# or java to loop through each document and edit it,

If you need help in writing a code I can give a small JAVA sample which can help. Just comment if you need.

Comment: I am not sure how to do this. I am using R and sometimes Python. Can I do the same in this programs, and how?

Comment: do you have the MongoDB drivers for Python?